# Internet Explorer does not change 'ß' (&szlig;/es-zed) to 'SS' when using 'text-transform: uppercase;'

Tags: html, internet-explorer, character, css

Internet Explorer 9 and 10 do not change the German *es-zed* "`ß`" (`&szlig;`, '*sz*') to "`SS`" properly when using the CSS rule `text-transform: uppercase;`. Is this simply not implemented or is it a bug that I can handle somehow in a way of not replacing all "`ß`" manually?

Comment: possibly related to localisation. Presume the site is in German; have you set the page headers to specify the language?

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 is used, file is also encoded in UTF-8 and language is set to `"de"`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a feature. CSS 2.1 does not define what uppercase and lowercase mean, and IE 9 treats U+00DF LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S “ß” so that its uppercase mapping is U+1E9E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S “ẞ” (there is a difference, though it can be difficult to see). This happens in “standards mode”; in Quirks Mode, IE 9 treats “ß” as its own uppercase mapping.

The feature is odd, because the *normal* way is to map “ß” to “SS”, and the uppercase “ẞ” was added some years ago for *optional* use in the relatively few situations where words are uppercased so that the distinction between e.g. the names Strauss and Strauß must be retained

The [CSS 3 Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#text-transform0) Working Draft specifies that case mappings shall be applied according to Unicode, and they map “ß” to “SS”. If it will become a recommendation, then the feature turns into a bug.

As a rule, doing case mappings in CSS is unreliable. It is better to generate the content in proper case, performing mappings server-side if needed. Then you can handle any special cases separately. You could also use client-side JavaScript; in JavaScript, case conversions are Unicode-aware (one of the few areas where JavaScript has been well globalized).

Comment: That's an awesome answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let ma add a question. I was wondering: Isn't text in uppercases treated differently by search engines? So I'm curious about pages where all headings are in uppercase letters. Could this be problematic when the text is already pre-processed?

Comment: @insertusernamehere, for that issue you might wish to open a new question, but current search engines seem to be case-ignorant. They might fail to treat ß and ẞ as equivalent to each other and to ss and SS, though. I’ll add a note on doing things client-side.

Comment: As of yesterday, it seams Internet Explorer 9 and 10 are the first browsers to do it right (there is now officaly a big sz in written German)